TypeError when importing pwntools
My python code is as follows
`
#! C:\user\myenv\Scripts\python.exe
from pwn import *

`
This is what i get when i run the code,
C:\user\myenv\Scripts\python.exe "c:\user\folderName\stringss.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\user\folderName\stringss.py", line 3, in <module>
from pwn import *
File "C:\user\myenv\lib\site-packages\pwn\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
from pwn.toplevel import *
File "C:\user\myenv\lib\site-packages\pwn\toplevel.py", line 21, in <module>
import pwnlib
File "C:\user\myenv\lib\site-packages\pwnlib\__init__.py", line 41, in <module>
from . import args
File "C:\user\myenv\lib\site-packages\pwnlib\args.py", line 60, in <module>
from pwnlib import term
File "C:\user\myenv\lib\site-packages\pwnlib\term\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
from pwnlib.term import completer
File "C:\user\myenv\lib\site-packages\pwnlib\term\completer.py", line 7, in <module>
from pwnlib.term import readline
File "C:\user\myenv\lib\site-packages\pwnlib\term\readline.py", line 14, in <module>
from pwnlib.term import text
File "C:\user\myenv\lib\site-packages\pwnlib\term\text.py", line 136, in <module>
sys.modules[__name__] = Module()
File "C:\user\myenv\lib\site-packages\pwnlib\term\text.py", line 30, in __init__
self.num_colors = termcap.get('colors', 8) if sys.platform == 'win32' else 8
File "C:\minuha\myenv\lib\site-packages\pwnlib\term\windows_termcap.py", line 26, in get
return s(*args)
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

`
Found nothing online so far. I have my virtual environment activated on vscode. There's no underline or error showing in the code. But it doesn't run either for some typeError

It may be the version of pwntools that your are using. I couldn't reproduce the problem with pwntools 4.9 or 4.10 but I did get different errors. I got no errors using 4.13.1.

I fixed the issue . Well I started a new venv and did the whole thing again and deleted the old one. It seems to work now. I don't know what went wrong the last time. But i'm glad it's working now.
